# How to import sql file when INSERT statement contains quotes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have sql file with lakhs of records. I need to import it into database. 
But
In this sql file many records have single quote in between records. SO during import I get error.

Anyone help me to import such file. Due to there are so many records I can not modify full file.

Example records

```
INSERT INTO `clients` VALUES(1, 'azienda', 'Azienda specializzata doesn't nel design 'di' sedie);
INSERT INTO `clients` VALUES(2, 'azienda', 'Azienda 'specializzata' nel design di sedie);
INSERT INTO `clients` VALUES(3, 'azienda', 'Azienda specializzata nel 'design' di sedie);
```

Comment: Can you modify the source to get formatted data?

Comment: how to created `lakhs records` sql file?

Comment: This file exported from another server and sent to me.

Comment: Let us know your default character set of your database

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%' => character_set_client  utf8, character_set_connection  utf8, character_set_database  latin1, character_set_database  latin1, character_set_system  utf8

Answer (score 0):

Steps to **import sql** file safely:
1. Take dump of your exiting database with following command

```
mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> <databasename> > /path/to/sqlfilename.sql
```

1. Now import this sql file into your database with this comman

   mysql -u -p databasename < /path/to/sqlfilename.sql

Comment: Poor comprehension skills

Comment: How did he created lakhs of records, i dont think he had written it, so I suggested him the method. In my opinion I suggested him the right method related to database import

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to export/import sql files. But we don't know if the OP has control over/access to the source. For all we know, it could well be the case that he was given the sql file and somehow he needs to import it.

Comment: this sql file I received from another source. he exported and sent to me. And it is not that easy to modify this much records.

Comment: It is not very hard to modify your data, It needs resources man!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Everything have a solution. But in your case, Best is to think about source of records.

**Option1:**
    Modify the source to get formatted data, I think that should be best way and also we can suggest best way for that. And import is easy like **mysql -u -p databasename < pathtosqlfile**

**Option2.** 
Use parser using any programming language and create new sql file, then import.

I suggest you for **option 1.**

Comment: as per optio one how can we modify this big file.

Comment: We have to write some rules to modify this file. But it takes time, you can write program in java/python/.. . I think this may not be hard because VALUES( *, *, *,..) is only one format which is fixed, so ask someone to write simple program to get this. Thanks. 1-2 hours may be enough for good programmer :)

Comment: this is not the way. If file is exported from sql, it should get imported. But I am facing this issue why?

Comment: You didn't understand my point, It's ok. If you wanna solution, then create another sql file using parser in your end.

Comment: can we do this while exporting file from mysql/phpmyadmin

Comment: You have to do before importing.